# I got confused to understand a Different between Classes & Functions in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, encoding, frontend, software-design

I got confused to understand a Different between Classes & Functions in React JS .

as you can see I wrote a code that show the user whom I followed with Class and function , please check it .
Consider this component:

```
function ProfilePage(props) {
  const showMessage = () => {
    alert('Followed ' + props.user);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setTimeout(showMessage, 3000);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Follow</button>
  );
}
```

It shows a button that simulates a network request with setTimeout and then shows a confirmation alert. For example, if props.user is 'Dan', it will show 'Followed Dan' after three seconds. Simple enough.

The same code but in class component

```
class ProfilePage extends React.Component {
  showMessage = () => {
    alert('Followed ' + this.props.user);
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    setTimeout(this.showMessage, 3000);
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Follow</button>;
  }
}
```

The App.js file

```
import ProfilePageFunction from './ProfilePageFunction';
import ProfilePageClass from './ProfilePageClass';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: 'Dan',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <label>
          <b>Choose profile to view: </b>
          <select
            value={this.state.user}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ user: e.target.value })}
          >
            <option value="Dan">Dan</option>
            <option value="Sophie">Sophie</option>
            <option value="Sunil">Sunil</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <h1>Welcome to {this.state.user}’s profile!</h1>
        <p>
          <ProfilePageFunction user={this.state.user} />
          <b> (function)</b>
        </p>
        <p>
          <ProfilePageClass user={this.state.user} />
          <b> (class)</b>
        </p>
        <p>
          Can you spot the difference in the behavior?
        </p>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Try this sequence of actions with both buttons:

1 Click one of the Follow buttons.
2 Change the selected profile before 3 seconds pass.
3 Read the alert text.

With the above ProfilePage function, clicking Follow on Dan’s profile and then navigating to Sophie’s would still alert 'Followed Dan'.
With the above ProfilePage class, it would alert 'Followed Sophie'

But why is That ??

try it here : https://codesandbox.io/s/pjqnl16lm7?file=/src/index.js:62-1024

Comment: With the class component the `showMessage` function is scoped to the class and created once (per instance), the timeout will call that instance of the function when triggering, this allows the props to change and for this change to be represented within the `showMessage` function called by the `setTimeout`. The function component recreates the `showMessage` function on each render scoped to the values available at that time, the `setTimeout` will trigger whatever function was referenced by `showMessage` when the timeout was originally created (not necessarily the current function).

Comment: see [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/the-definitive-guide-to-react-class-vs-functional-components-481b1157ed08)